# NodeJS Epxress + Angular 7 русская маршрутизация

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular7

Столкнулся с проблемой серверного рендеринга (Angular Universal). Дело в том что имеется доменное имя типа "сайт.рф", и на сайте используется русская маршрутизация, вот код модуля маршрутизации app-routing.module.ts.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', children: [
    {path: '', component: MiddlewareComponent, children: [
      {path: '', component: MainComponent},
      {path: 'сантехник', component: PlumberComponent},
      {path: 'сантехник/:urlName', component: PlumberChildComponent},
      {path: 'электрик', component: ElectricianComponent},
      {path: 'электрик/:urlName', component: ElectricianChildComponent},
      {path: 'услуги', component: BuilderComponent},
      {path: 'услуги/:urlName', component: BuilderChildComponent},
    ]}
  ]},
  {path: 'контакты', component: ContactsComponent},
  {path: 'вакансии', component: VacancyComponent},
  {path: 'карта-сайта', component: MapsiteComponent},
  {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
];
```

При переходе на какую либо страницу, которая использует русскую символику, выдается ошибка:

```
ERROR TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters
```

Предполагаю проблема как раз из-за русской маршрутизации.

Вопрос: Как можно решить эту проблему на стороне NodeJS, без изменения доменного имени и путей маршрутизации.

Comment: 1. непонятно почему у вас возникает это ошибка, сервер должен просто на все запросы отдавать отрендеренную страницу 2. на сервер не летит url вида `сантехник`, браузер кодирует в `%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA` 3. на сервере нужно декодировать через `decodeURI` чтоб Angular мог сопоставить урл с конфигурацией

Comment: @overthesanity, 3 - разве ангуляр сам этого не делает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет .

Answer (score 1):

Было найдено очевидное решение, как говорил @overthesanity, в файле server.js была найдена строка

```
      request = hxxp.request({
        hostname: this._url.hostname,
        port: this._url.port,
        path: this._url.path,
        auth: this._url.auth,
        method: this._method,
        headers: this._headers,
        agent: agent
      });
```

И заменена на

```
      request = hxxp.request({
        hostname: encodeURI(this._url.hostname),
        port: this._url.port,
        path: encodeURI(this._url.path),
        auth: this._url.auth,
        method: this._method,
        headers: this._headers,
        agent: agent
      });
```